# Adding 'utf-8' parameter to occurrences of htmlspecialchars() - can it break anything?

Tags: php, character-encoding, escaping, htmlspecialchars

Assuming my project is utf-8 throughout and has always been used with utf-8 encoding, is there anything legit that could possibly break if I change all occurrences of **`htmlspecialchars($var)`** to **`htmlspecialchars($var, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8')`**?

I do know one thing: Obviously, `ENT_QUOTES` differs from `ENT_COMPAT` in that it also escapes single quotation marks. Assuming I know that this alone won't break anything, is there anything else left over?

Differently worded:

Is there a conceivable result of **htmlspecialchars()** when used without the charset parameter, *given data only from the charset*, that would differ from **htmlspecialchars()** when used *with* the charset parameter?

(Is, at any point, `htmlspecialchars($stringThatIsValidUTF8, ENT_QUOTES) !== htmlspecialchars($stringThatIsValidUTF8, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8')`?)

My understanding says no, never. [Another question here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839203/php-htmlspecialchars-and-utf-8) suggests no, too. So far, browsing my sandbox of the project with the changes also says no. However, I'm not sure if I'm overlooking something.

Comment: I know I've had problems with 'utf-8' as an arg of htmlentities, but unfortunately I can't recall exactly what those were.  Do, however, watch out for Windows-1252 "smart quotes" (commonly from MS Word) and other characters in that range (especially in user-submitted content).  Specifically, UTF8 range `\xC280-\xC29F` and Windows-1252 range `\x80-\x9F`; as well as the high ASCII chars `\x81\x8D\x8F\x90\x9D`.

Comment: @Frank, but those are not going to be subject to htmlspecialchars() are they? htmlspecialchars() does only `&"'<>`. htmlentities() is a different matter.

Comment: Good catch on the htmlentities(). That would probably be trickier, and is good to keep in mind. Thanks for the feedback, guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the quote from the PHP manual in the other question answers it definitely:

> For the purposes of this function, the charsets ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-15, UTF-8, cp866, cp1251, cp1252, and KOI8-R are effectively equivalent, as the characters affected by htmlspecialchars() occupy the same positions in all of these charsets.

`"` `&` `>` and so on all have the same code in each of those encodings, and even in UTF-8 they require only one byte, because an UTF-8 character will occupy multiple bytes only when necessary. Therefore, even if you have been processing UTF-8 data with  ISO-8859-1 until now, the output will be identical when you switch to explicit UTF-8 input.

Comment: I love when people just quote the manual ! (i.e. +1 for RTXM)

Comment: It's a re-quote actually, from the question @pinkgothic is linking to, so it was not *really* meant as RTFM :)

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much. Thanks for confirming and soothing my paranoia! :D Much appreciated.

Comment: It is worth noting that they behave quite differently when the input is not valid UTF-8. From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php#refsect1-function.htmlspecialchars-returnvalues): *If the input string contains an invalid code unit sequence within the given charset and the ENT_IGNORE flag is not set, then htmlspecialchars() will return an empty string.*

Answer (score -1):

No, it wouldn't differ, becouse if you didn't provide any charset, PHP will guess it, therefore it will use UTF-8.

Comment: That is *totally* wrong. PHP < 5.4.0 will *assume* ISO-8859-1 and >= 5.4.0 will *assume* UTF-8.